# Can I use 2 different subdomains with 2 different servers?

Tags: apache-2.2, subdomain

I have 2 different servers and one domain name. Can I use 2 different sub domains to point to the two servers? Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. This would all be controlled through [DNS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System).

You can set up, for example, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) to 203.0.113.2 and home.example.com to 203.0.113.3.

You could theoretically go [turtles all the way down](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down) and make subdomains of your subdomains.  The address [www.chicago.illinois.us.example.com](http://www.chicago.illinois.us.example.com) is perfectly valid, though cumbersome.

(edited to conform to [RFC 5737](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5737) for IP address examples)

Comment: +1 for the phrase "go tutles"